# Pocket API Access Token Request

Tags: python, api, oauth, token

I'm trying to get an Access Token from [Pockets API](http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/authentication)

I'm able to succesfully get a Request Token, but when I try to use that to get the Access Token, it fails with a 400 bad request error.

Here's the code:

```
def getAccessToken(request_code):
    headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8','X-Accept': 'application/json'}
    request_data = json.dumps({"consumer_key":["12092-2970cc0e27ce9a25cb39f1dd"],"code":["af0f6c9b-815b-cd1d-9864-b6d375"]})
    url = "https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/authorize"

    response_data = makeRequest(headers,request_data,url)
    access_code, username = response_data['access_token'],response_data['username']

    return access_code,username

def makeRequest(request_headers,request_data,request_url):
    request = urllib2.Request(request_url,request_data,request_headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    data = json.load(response)

    return data
```

I just can't seem to figure it out. I'm pretty sure the Request Token is valid (any way to confirm?), I go through redirecting to the Pockets authorization page, click authorize and I get redirected to the redirect_uri. On getting the redirect_uri, that's when I call getAccessToken()

If I need to provide any extra information please let me know. Thanks for any help.

Update:

Looking further into this problem, Pocket has a list of HTTPError descriptions. The one I'm throwing is 138 - Missing consumer key.

This makes even less sense now, as I'm using the exact same consumer key to obtain the request token.

Response headers:

> ```
> Cache-Control: private
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> Date: Sun, 03 Mar 2013 03:54:01 GMT
> P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="ALL CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND UNI COM NAV INT STA PRE"
> Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Amazon)
> Status: 400 Bad Request
> X-Error: Missing consumer key.
> X-Error-Code: 138
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `[` and `]` from `{"consumer_key":["12092-2970cc0e27ce9a25cb39f1dd"],`. You are passing a list, where probably you should be passing a string. That *should* fix it.

Comment: Oh man. It worked. Thanks Burhan, I've been going at this for hours. You're the best.

Comment: I concur about you being the best @Burhan!